# IntentService loses connection with internet

Tags: java, android, intentservice, miui

I have problem with my IntentService. I need my service to access JSON file in website every 1 minute in background, without app being open (To make notification, which I receive in JSON). It does that, but after 3-4 minutes, it throws "**java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out**" error and I can still resolve domain to IP address, but I cannot connect to website, and phone still have mobile connection. Same thing happens with all websites.

My IntentService:

```
public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {

Runnable runnable = () -> new bgJob().execute();
Handler handler = new Handler();
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

public BackgroundService() {
    super("BackgroundService");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    runnable.run();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    Log.d("BG_SERVICE","TASK REMOVED!");
    Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
    restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    myAlarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartPendingIntent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("BG_SERVICE","TASK DESTROYED!");
    Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
    restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    myAlarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartPendingIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "MyWakelockTag");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    runnable.run();
}



private class bgJob extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://google.com/")
                    .build();
            Response response = null;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                int webresponse = response.code();
                Log.d("Response","CODE: "+webresponse);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 60000);
    }
}}
```

I am using Android 7.0 on my phone with mobile connection.

Comment: That will not be possible on Android 6.0+ devices. Users are *very tired* of developers thinking that they need to communicate with their servers that frequently and causing harm to the user (draining the battery, consuming too much bandwidth, etc.). Doze mode, app standby, and background execution limits added in recent Android versions are there specifically to prevent what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CommonsWare So there is no way, I can receive this JSON information in background? And how does applications like Whatsapp receive new messages in background?

Comment: "So there is no way, I can receive this JSON information in background?" -- sure you can. You just cannot do it continuously, every minute, by polling a server. "And how does applications like Whatsapp receive new messages in background?" -- I assume that they use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Go to settings -> battery usage and allow the mobile to use services even in the background or if the screen is off. In most of the recent mobiles it will be disabled for saving battery life.

Comment: @RakeshPolo I think it wouldn't be ideal solution, because then every app user would need to do that.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay, thanks for answer.

Comment: Not every mobile needs it. Only in some brands like redmi i faced this problem. You just need to inform the user to make sure he has enbled that function through a splash screen or a pop up.

Comment: @RakeshPolo Okay. And the phone I am trying the app is Redmi.

Comment: lol yeah as i told you. Even i had faced the same problem i think except redmi no brand is restricting background services. so just enable that option in battery usage. The service will work forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow the instructions given [here](https://www.hrupin.com/2017/03/how-to-keep-background-activities-in-xiaomi-redmi-note-3-with-miui-8-1-3-0) As for as my knowledge is concerned only redmi mobiles have this problem. So get the brand name in your activity like this.

```
String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String model = Build.MODEL;
```

and using this you can notify only the redmi users to enable background service access.